# ASP.NET MVC cannot POST view model with binding to checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, checkbox, viewmodel, model-binding

Here are my view models:

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    public User GroupUser { get; set; }
    public bool Checked { get; set; }
}

public class GroupUserViewModel
{
    public Guid GroupId { get; set; }
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
    public IList<UserViewModel> Users;        
}
```

My view:

```
@model GroupUserViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Users";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>@Model.GroupName</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("AddUserToGroup", "Group", FormMethod.Post))
{
    for (var userIter = 0; userIter < Model.Users.Count(); userIter++)
    {
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Users[userIter].GroupUser.UserName)
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Users[userIter].Checked)

            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.GroupId)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.GroupName)
        </div>        
    }

    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Save"/>
}
```

My controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddUserToGroup(GroupUserViewModel groupUsers)
{
    //do things    
}
```

I had an inspection of the POST data and it is:

```
Users[0].Checked=true
Users[0].Checked=false
Users[1].Checked=false
```

For the boxes I've ticked there are 2 entries, one `true` and one `false`. Is this normal?

Also in the controller, what I get back is:

```
groupUsers.GroupId = {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
groupUsers.GroupName = null
groupUsers.Users = null
```

Obviously since the form isn't actually posting the view model I want back to the controller, this happens. Is there any way to pass the required view model back to the controller since I need the `GroupId` and `GroupName`?

EDIT:

After some updates and adding in hidden fields for `GroupId` and `GroupName`, now the POST data is:

```
Users[0].Checked=true
Users[0].Checked=false
Id=015f5aef-eb6c-449e-9f08-9d42110c5347
GroupName=MyName
MyObjects[1].Checked=false
Id=015f5aef-eb6c-449e-9f08-9d42110c5347
GroupName=MyName
```

The `GroupId` and `GroupName` are now being passed corrently but the list is still `null`.

Comment: Yes that is normal. If you inspect the html you will see a checkbox with `value="true"` and an associated hidden input with `value="false"`. This ensures a value is posted because unchecked checkboxes do not post back a value. The `DefaultModelBinder` will bind the first one and ignore the second one with the same name.

Comment: The view code you have shown does not include form controls for `Id` and `Name` so they will be the defaults. The collection will bind based on the code you have shown (it should be `@Html.CheckBoxFor(m=> m.MyObjects[i].Selected)` but assume that's a typo)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks for the info. Okay so the ```Id``` and ```Name``` are getting passed now but the list of objects is still null.

Comment: Should be. Are you sure that's the real code?

Comment: Well it's stripped down version of the real code with different variable names. I did copy and paste to make sure.

Comment: Then its something else in your code which you have not shown us is causing the issue. Show your real code (possible issues are having an input for the collection or having a parameter name which is the same as your model property

Comment: @StephenMuecke Updated.

Comment: `public IList<UserViewModel> Users;` is a field, not a property so the `DefaultModelBinder` cannot **set** the value - add `{ get; set; }`

Comment: Side note: your inputs for `GroupId` and `GroupName` should be outside the loop

Comment: Thank you very much. I now feel a little silly since I did actually see another answer saying this but I still missed it in my own code.

Comment: Just ensure in future you post your real code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IList<UserViewModel> Users` in `GroupUserViewModel` is a field, not a property so the `DefaultModelBinder` cannot set its value. Change it to

```
public class GroupUserViewModel
{
    ....
    public IList<UserViewModel> Users { get; set; } // make it a property   
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes this is normal. The reason is because an unchecked checkbox will not post a value, so ASP.NET renders a hidden field for every checkbox with the same ID as the checkbox just after the checkbox control, and sets its value to false. ASP.NET DefaultModelBinder will, if there are multiple form fields with the same name, take the first value. This results in one value of false being posted from the hidden field if the checkbox is not checked, and two values, one of false for the hidden field and one of true for the checked checkbox. Because the hidden field comes after the checkbox, if the checkbox posts a value, it will override the hidden field.
However, that doesn't answer your question as to why the model isn't binding..

Comment: Probably b/c you didn't answer his question. A comment (like Stephen's) would've been better.

Comment: +1 for ASP.NET DefaultModelBinder will, if there are multiple form fields with the same name, take the first value